# Android Custom ToolBar Covers entire Screen

Tags: android, tabs, toolbar

I created a custom toolbar to show at the top of my Tab Layout activity. After including it in my activity's xml, it acts as a background color(ORANGE) to different Fragment tabs of my Tab Layout.

Here
[image]

ToolBar xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_clashmate"
    android:elevation="4dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

TabLayout Activity's XML (Where to add toolbar at the top)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#dfdfdf"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/PrimaryColor"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
    <include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

How to set it to Top of the activity where i can further add buttons to it?

Comment: You have clearly mentioned the height of toolbar as Match Parent. Use Wrap content instead

Comment: use `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"` for toolbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your toolbar to this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_clashmate"
    android:elevation="4dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to the ToolBar placed into an element (`TabLayout)` that have `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

That causes the problem

Use this to set height of `ToolBar` corresponding to the default `ActionBar` height

```
android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:background="#dfdfdf"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/testtoolbar"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 </LinearLayout>
 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```